# Does both switch and router have to be gigabit for higher speeds?

Tags: switch, router, ethernet, speed

If you have a gigabit switch connected to non-gigabit router, will the internal network transfer rates be gigabit when the devices are connected to the switch, or will the router also have to have a gigabit port?

Comment: I edited the question to be on-topic; however, you should ask questions about consumer networking equipment on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have VLAN segmentation?  If so - I would assume the 'routing point' for your network is the router, in which case any traffic going between VLANs would traverse the uplink from the GIG switch to the non-gig router.  I'm also assuming the speed of your 'non-gig' router is 100mb?  Depending on what the network is being used for, and how many users - that 100mb link can be adequate bandwidth or it can be saturated constantly.  The only sure way to know would be to check interface statistics during peak transfer periods - on a Cisco Device:

```
 show interface Fa0/x
 show interface Gi0/x
```

If the traffic flow is not between VLANs (hosts that are plugged into the switch are all on the same VLANs) - then they would not be using that link to the router as they are all on the same broadcast domain.  Assuming all ports negotiated at 1 Gig -  you would get 1 Gig speeds.

If this is (as Mike P. classified off topic) a home router/switch question - then I would think the bottleneck would be the ISP speed (unless you've got Gig speeds there).

Answer (score 1):

If 2 hosts have gigabit interfaces and connected both to the same gigabit switch and both ports belong to the same VLAN then it will be gigabit connection. Traffic through 100M router will be 100M